# Should server-side objects contain all database columns/relationships at creation time?

Tags: database, web, structure

I am an unexperienced computer science student and while making projects for different courses a few conceptual questions occurred.

Say I am to develop a website similar to imdb, but for music, from scratch and I want to list some artists on the frontpage.
The database schema is already done with all its relationship and attributes, and there is a table artists.
Should my server-side artist-class contain all table columns and relationships at creation time even it is not necessarily needed at that time?
Or should I construct these objects with minimal parameters (like id, name) and get all the rest when needed (resulting in more individual sql statements) via helper-methods?
I know that there is maybe no definitive answer except for 'it depends' or boils down to personal preference, but maybe there is even a consensus.
If someone could name or link to resources to read up on things like this I would be very grateful, I didn't know what to search for exactly. Thanks.

PS: For people wondering why I don't ask these questions in the CS course; they are mostly held by students/assistants who only had to pass the course and don't have that much experience themselves.

Comment: " Or should I construct these objects with minimal parameters (like id, name) and get all the rest when needed (resulting in more individual sql statements) via helper-methods? " - Can you elaborate this a bit more? Do you mean that you will go and add other attributes to the classes as and when the requirement is there? Or something else

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what this means so I am answering assuming this does not exist in the question. Will edit answer when clarification is given.

> Or should I construct these objects with minimal parameters (like id, name) and get all the rest when needed (resulting in more individual sql statements) via helper-methods?

**Actual answer starts here**

It does not boil down to personal preference but whether you can or cannot find a practical reason to do something. All design patterns follow practicality instead of personal preferences. Even if there is a consensus you can always ask why.

If there are 100 tables in the database already present and in my web application I can get by with just 2 of them I don't see a reason why I should sit down and create all 100 tables in my web application's domain model. It's just not logical.

There may be some cases when a big application is being created and we are like 99% sure that we will need to model all of it and that requires us to model a bit more classes (say 5 instead of 2) for ensuring that our future work is not hindered.

Also there is the concern of data integerity. Does those 2 tables depend on some other table? Do some table depend on them? If there is a dependency then you might need to include those tables also.

FYI such questions are better suited on [programmers stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour)